# Why didn't Obi-Wan and Yoda train Luke from a young age?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, obi-wan-kenobi, jedi-training

I feel like I should note that I've watched the Star Wars movies as a kid, but it has been a while, and I may have missed/forgotten a lot of details along the way. Also, the movies are all I've seen. I've never read any of the books or anything like that.

I was wondering why Obi-Wan Kenobi and Yoda didn't train Luke from the time he was very young. Obi-Wan knew where Yoda was, so the two of them could have trained Luke from a very young age. They could have helped him become very strong by the time the first movie began. Why didn't they do that? Why was giving Luke to his aunt and uncle more preferable?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12410/was-obi-wan-subtly-preparing-luke-for-training

Comment: @Ixrec One of the questions linked in that question actually answers my question, I think. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45188/31260

Answer (score 2):

My recollection is that they did not want Darth Vader or the emperor to know where Luke and his sister were. The anonymity was at least as important as the other reasons given in the link you gave. If Darth Vader and the emperor raised Luke and his sister, the dark side might have become insurmountable. And if Luke and his sister knew their true lineage as children, they may not have given the good side a chance. A secret such as their identity could not have been maintained if they grew up as Jedi. Better for them to remain anonymous until they were needed. ... And the living force described in your link would have prepared them by that time.